# SQLite group by a non-calendar month (from 10th in one month to 10th in next month)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, group-by

I'm an Android programmer, and I use SQLite (don't have much choice :) ) in my app.
I have a table, that contains a field of unix time stamp. Right now, if I want to make a sum of some field in this table, and group by months, I just do:

SELECT  month, year, sum(x)
FROM foo
GROUP BY month, year

(Of course that the month and year are date functions).

But I want to group it by non calendar month, like from the 10th of one month, to the 10th that comes after him.

I have a very basic knowledge in SQL so I have no clue on how to do it.
Someone told me I need to use PARTITION BY but SQLite doesn't support it.
I'm pretty sure there's a way to do it.

Thanks in advance,
Elad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle the tenth of the month, you can just subtract that 10 days from the date:

```
select strftime("%y %m", tendaysbefore), <whatever>
from (select foo.*,
             date(thedate, '-10 days') as tendaysbefore
      from foo
     ) t
group by strftime("%Y-%m", tendaysbefore)
order by 1, 2
```

You can put the year and month into separate columns.  This example has them in one column.

Comment: I need to subtract those ten days from current month and add them to the previous month, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand.  You have a reporting date.  If you report by the month in that date, you get the days in the month.  If you subtract 10 days, then the first ten days will appear in the previous month.  This will work for whatever month you are using, whether the current date or some other date.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you right, I think I got your idea, please correct me if not. You first make a query and taking all the dates in the table 10 days earlier, so now when you'll make query, it'll be "regular" query that just do group by, by month and year. So if for example, I will want to group by from 20th to 20th it will be `date(thedate, '-20 days')`. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If, perchance, you want the current month for the 10th (so 11 May - 10 Jun goes to Jun rather than May), then you would add one month to the date.

Comment: So simple yet very clever solution. Thanks a lot!